# does address of a protobuf member change when use set method?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf like this

```
message Proto{
    string  Data = 1;
}
```

and use it like this

```
Proto prot;
const s8* szData = prot.data().c_str();
```

what confuse me is that when I set data, it seems the content in szData is not the same with prot.data(), and after some test I found the address of prot.data changes

for example the following code:

```
// original
cout << static_cast<const void *>(szData) << ":"
<< static_cast<const void *>(prot.data().c_str()) << endl;

// set for the first time
prot.set_data("11");
cout << static_cast<const void *>(szData) << ":"
<< static_cast<const void *>(prot.data().c_str()) << endl;

// set for the second time
prot.set_data("12");
cout << static_cast<const void *>(szData) << ":"
<< static_cast<const void *>(prot.data().c_str()) << endl;
```

will produce something like this:

```
0x63ef618:0x63ef618
0x63ef618:0x63ef318
0x63ef618:0x63ef618
```

szData can also be filled with some nonsense content,Can any one be so kind explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protobuf compiler generates for your message class something like this:

```
class ProtoClass {
  // getters
  const string& data() { return data; }

  // setters
  void set_data (const string& d) {
    data = d; // [1]
  }

  void set_data (string&& d) {
    data = move(d); // [2]
  }
  // other members

private:
  string data;
};
```

There is difference between address of data to data member of `ProtoClass` (pointer to `data`) and a pointer to content of data string (what `c_str()` returns when calling `data.c_str()`).

Every time you call `set_data` you modify `data` member, by calling copy/move assignment operators ([1],[2]), these operators don't change address of `data` member but they modify internal pointer of data string. 
After every call of `set_data` address of string returned by `prot.data()` is still the same, 
`set_data` doesn't perform any operations which can change address of this object. 
Only the content of string is modified what you observed by printing `c_str()` value.